# How to get the Scroll position in a WebView ? (Android 1.6)

Tags: android, scroll

I have tried to use this answer :

> I've found a better answer to this issue. It turns out that WebView
>   does have scrollTo(), getScrollX() and getScrollY() methods as you'd
>   expect. They're a bit hidden in the documentation because they're
>   inherited from View (via AbsoluteLayout -> ViewGroup -> View). This is
>   obviously a better way to manipulate the WebView's scroll position
>   than the somewhat cumbersome JavaScript interface.

But all the times i try , it tells me it has a 0 scrolX and a 0 scrollY.

Any idea of how must i do this?

Comment: I have the same problem. After so much time, did you manage to set scroll of a webview programatically?

Comment: @LuisA.Florit At the end i've upgraded to 2.1 , since 1.6 is out of market and use.

Comment: sorry, but how that solved your problem?